# TSQL Поменять код телефона с +7499 на +7495 (вместо +7 может быть другой код) н

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Проект таблицы
Код преподавателя   int
Фамилия nchar(50)
Имя nchar(50)
Отчество    nchar(50)
Стоимость часа  decimal(18, 0)
Контактный телефон  nvarchar(20)
Образование nchar(50)

Так же есть код который меняет 495 на 499

```
SELECT * 
    , result = IIF(SUBSTRING(Контактный_телефон,2,3)='499', STUFF(Контактный_телефон,2,3,'495'), Контактный телефон)
FROM Запрос2;
```

Comment: Меняйте, разрешаем :)

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 2):

Это похоже на повторяющийся вопрос: [TSQL Задание на выборку поменять код телефона в таблице с 499 на 495](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365303/tsql-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81-499-%d0%bd%d0%b0-495)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, phone VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl (phone) VALUES
('8499 931-97-04'),
('8499 499-97-02'),
('8495 931-97-07'),
('+7499 499-97-18');
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

SELECT * 
    , result = IIF(SUBSTRING(phone, 2 + pos, 3)='499', STUFF(phone, 2 + pos, 3, '495'), phone)
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(LEFT(phone,1)='+',1,0)) AS t(pos);
```

**Результат**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| ID |      phone      |     result      |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | 8499 931-97-04  | 8495 931-97-04  |
|  2 | 8499 499-97-02  | 8495 499-97-02  |
|  3 | 8495 931-97-07  | 8495 931-97-07  |
|  4 | +7499 499-97-18 | +7495 499-97-18 |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```