# TSQL Изменить код телефона с 499 на 495 , можно использовать Case

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, сервер

```
SELECT * FROM Запрос2
Update Запрос2 Set Контактный телефон =
CASE
WHEN substring(Контактный телефон, 2, 3) = '499' then '495'
END
WHERE substring(Контактный телефон, 2, 3) = '499'
```

Есть вот такой запрос, но он меняет не только код телефона, а весь номер
например у меня было 84995671234 а стало просто 495
как починить???

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [TSQL Поменять код телефона с +7499 на +7495 (вместо +7 может быть другой код) н](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366153/tsql-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81-7499-%d0%bd%d0%b0-7495-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-7-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd)

Comment: @Petya, Прекратите играть с нами в игры, касающиеся ваших данных. Вам необходимо предоставить ## 1-4.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (phone varchar(11))
insert into @t (phone) values ('84995671234'), ('84951171234'), ('84994991234'), (null), ('74991234567'), ('84990');

update @t 
set phone = '8495' + SUBSTRING(phone,5,LEN(phone)-4)
where phone like '8499%';

select * from @t;
```

Comment: а если телефон будет иметь вид вот такой :
+74957779999

Comment: @Petya, Прекратите играть с нами в игры, касающиеся ваших данных. Вам необходимо предоставить ## 1-4.